# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS changing OOMScoreAdjust in /lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service has no effect

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, systemd

As title, I have my postgresql@.service done as follows:

```
 # systemd service template for PostgreSQL clusters. The actual instances will
# be called "postgresql@version-cluster", e.g. "postgresql@9.3-main". The
# variable %i expands to "version-cluster", %I expands to "version/cluster".
# (%I breaks for cluster names containing dashes.)

[Unit]
Description=PostgreSQL Cluster %i
ConditionPathExists=/etc/postgresql/%I/postgresql.conf
PartOf=postgresql.service
ReloadPropagatedFrom=postgresql.service
Before=postgresql.service

[Service]
Type=forking
# @: use "postgresql@%i" as process name
ExecStart=@/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster postgresql@%i --skip-systemctl-redirect %i start
ExecStop=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect -m fast %i stop
ExecReload=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect %i reload
PIDFile=/var/run/postgresql/%i.pid
SyslogIdentifier=postgresql@%i
# prevent OOM killer from choosing the postmaster (individual backends will
# reset the score to 0)
OOMScoreAdjust=-999
# restarting automatically will prevent "pg_ctlcluster ... stop" from working,
# so we disable it here. Also, the postmaster will restart by itself on most
# problems anyway, so it is questionable if one wants to enable external
# automatic restarts.
#Restart=on-failure
# (This should make pg_ctlcluster stop work, but doesn't:)
#RestartPreventExitStatus=SIGINT SIGTERM

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then I cat the /proc/pid/oom_score_adj, it still always shows the default value which is -900. I wonder what has gone wrong?

Comment: I don't know if you got a notification when I undeleted my answer after editing with a working solution, but you should get the comment notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service defined by `/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service` starts-up `/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster`. Inside `pg_ctlcluster` we find this:

```
if ($action eq 'start' and $version >= '9.0' and not $PgCommon::rpm) {
    if (-w '/proc/self/oom_score_adj') {
        open F, '>/proc/self/oom_score_adj';
        print F "-900\n";
        close F;
    } 
}
```

It seems like Postgres' own scripts set the value when starting-up. I edited it to `-999` and it did the job.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reload the service after making changes, or to be absolutely sure the change takes affects, stop the service and then start it again.

```
# maybe
systemctl reload postgresql@9.3-main

# definitely
systemctl stop postgresql@9.3-main
systemctl start postgresql@9.3-main
```

Comment: Already tried, even with systemctl daemon-reload still no luck.